# Hive: How do I compare two columns in WHERE clause having complex datatypes?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2, beeline

I have a hive table that acts as my source table.
I also have one more hive table that acts as target.
The DDL of both the source table and target table is same, except that a few journaling columns have been added in the target table.
Below are the DDLs:
Source:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE source.customer_detail(
   id string,
   name string,
   city string,
   properties_owned array<struct<property_addr:string, location:string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
  '/user/aiman/customer_detail';
```

Target:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE target.customer_detail(
   id string,
   name string,
   city string,
   properties_owned array<struct<property_addr:string, location:string>>
   audit_insterted_ts timestamp,
   audit_dml_action char(1)
)
PARTITIONED BY (audit_active_flag char(1))
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION
  '/user/aiman/target/customer_detail';
```

Data at Source:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| customer_detail.id  |   customer_detail.name   |  customer_detail.city   |                                               customer_detail.properties_owned                                                       |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1                   | Aiman Sarosh             |      kolkata            |  [{"property_addr":"H1 Block Saltlake","location":"kolkata"},{"property_addr":"New Property Added Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}]   |
| 2                   | Justin                   |      delhi              |  [{"property_addr":"some address in delhi","location":"delhi"}]                                                                      |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Data at Target:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| customer_detail.id  |   customer_detail.name   |  customer_detail.city   |              customer_detail.properties_owned                    |  customer_detail.audit_insterted_ts  | customer_detail.audit_dml_action  | customer_detail.audit_active_flag  |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 1                   | Aiman Sarosh             |      kolkata            |  [{"property_addr":"H1 Block Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}]    | 2018-09-04 06:55:12.361              | I                                 | A                                  |
| 2                   | Justin                   |      delhi              |  [{"property_addr":"some address in delhi","location":"delhi"}]  | 2018-09-05 08:36:39.023              | I                                 | A                                  |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

When I run the query below, it should fetch me 1 record that has been modified, i.e.:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| customer_detail.id  |   customer_detail.name   |  customer_detail.city   |                                                                  customer_detail.properties_owned                                              |  customer_detail.audit_insterted_ts  | customer_detail.audit_dml_action  | customer_detail.audit_active_flag  |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 1                   | Aiman Sarosh             |      kolkata            |  [{"property_addr":"H1 Block Saltlake","location":"kolkata"},{"property_addr":"New Property Added Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}]             | 2018-09-05 07:15:10.321              | U                                 | A                                  |
+---------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Basically, `{"property_addr":"New Property Added Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}` element has been added to array column `properties_owned` for record ID 1 at the `source`.

Query:

```
SELECT  --fetch modified/updated records in source
   source.id AS id,
   source.name AS name,
   source.city AS city,
   source.properties_owned AS properties_owned,
   current_timestamp() AS audit_insterted_ts,
   'U' AS audit_dml_action,
   'A' AS audit_active_flag
FROM source.customer_detail source
INNER JOIN target.customer_detail jrnl
ON source.id=jrnl.id
WHERE source.name!=jrnl.name
OR source.city!=jrnl.city
OR source.properties_owned!=jrnl.properties_owned
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 14:3 Argument type mismatch 'properties_owned': The 1st argument of NOT EQUAL  is expected to a primitive type, but list is found (state=42000,code=10016)
```

How do I compare two columns in WHERE clause having complex datatypes, when I am using JOINS ?
I can use `.POS` and `.ITEM` but this wont be helpful because my column is an **array of structure** and the length of array can be different.

Comment: You can use `lateral view explode` to explode your arrays then perform joins

Comment: I have tried to use that, but I cannot figure out what JOINs do I apply. any sample query would be of real help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using `LATERAL VIEW explode()`.
And then used `concat_ws()` in conjunction with `collect_list(array<string>)` method on the exploded columns, which finally gave me a single `string` which I compared:

```
SELECT  --fetch modified/updated records in source
   source.id AS id,
   source.name AS name,
   source.city AS city,
   source.properties_owned AS properties_owned,
   current_timestamp() AS audit_insterted_ts,
   'U' AS audit_dml_action,
   'A' AS audit_active_flag
FROM source.customer_detail source
INNER JOIN target.customer_detail jrnl
ON source.id=jrnl.id
WHERE source.id IN
(
SELECT t1.id
FROM
(
   SELECT src.id,concat_ws(',', collect_list(src.property_addr),collect_list(src.location)) newcol
   FROM
   (
      SELECT id, prop_owned.property_addr AS property_addr, prop_owned.location AS location
      FROM source.customer_detail LATERAL VIEW explode(properties_owned) exploded_tab AS prop_owned
   ) src
   GROUP BY src.id
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT trg.id,concat_ws(',', collect_list(trg.property_addr),collect_list(trg.location)) newcol
   FROM
   (
      SELECT id, prop_owned.property_addr AS property_addr, prop_owned.location AS location
      FROM target.customer_detail LATERAL VIEW explode(properties_owned) exploded_tab AS prop_owned
   ) trg
   GROUP BY trg.id
) t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.newcol!=t2.newcol
```

Hope someone finds this useful and helpful.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle complex types is to convert them to String, for instance Json string. There is [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse.git) project with helpful third-party Hive UDFs. It has `to_json` function that can convert any complex type to json string. First, clone and build the jar:

```
git clone https://github.com/klout/brickhouse.git
cd brickhouse
mvn clean package
```

then copy Brickhouse jar to HDFS and add the jar in Hive:

```
add jar hdfs://<your_path>/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
```

register `to_json` UDF in Hive

```
create temporary function to_json as 'brickhouse.udf.json.ToJsonUDF';
```

Now you can use it, e.g.,

```
hive> select to_json(ARRAY(MAP('a',1), MAP('b',2)));
OK
[{"a":1},{"b":2}]
```

So in your case you need to convert you column to json string then compare in `where` clause. Keep in mind that `to_json` converts a complex value as it is. For example, in your case two arrays

```
[{"property_addr":"H1 Block Saltlake","location":"kolkata"},{"property_addr":"New Property Added Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}]
```

and

```
[{"property_addr":"New Property Added Saltlake","location":"kolkata"},{"property_addr":"H1 Block Saltlake","location":"kolkata"}]
```

will be different.

Comment: Thanks serge_k. Thats a nice way. But I implemented it using `lateral view explode()` and a subquery to get one column and use `collect_list` and `concat_ws` and then compare.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You are trying to compare lists instead of primitive types

Current situation: There is no way to do a direct comparison of list of complex objects with build-in Hive udfs (There are some workarounds for list of strings).

Workaround: You will need some third party UDFs to help you on this. There are a few interesting udfs [here](https://github.com/aaronshan/hive-third-functions) (I have not tested those before)